# Using in json constant value from python file

Tags: json, python-2.7

I have two files. The first one is python file with some config constants defined. The second one is the json file where I would like to use one of these constants. Can I use the constant defined in python file in json file? How to import it and use it?

settings.py

```
MAX_SIZE = 100
```

settings.json

```
parameters:[
  {
    "max_size": MAX_SIZE
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can access MAX_SIZE directly from JSON without an actual language implementation in between.

What you can do is the inverse - import "settings.json" into your settings.py file and then edit the imported json.

Pseudocode (in your settings.py file):

```
import parameters from settings.json

MAX_SIZE = 100

//Assign constant value to json object
parameters[0].max_size = MAX_SIZE
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I did meanwhile.